# Cocoa App: How to find running process

Tags: xcode, cocoa, process, instruments, nstask

my app Cocoa app for OS X was rejected by Apple. This is what they said:

> 2.23 The app spawns a process that continues running after the user quits the app, without first obtaining user consent.
>   The spawned
>   process is /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp -psn_0_10148269.

*(I changed the app name)*

I have no idea how to find out what this strange process is. What's the best approach to find that out? Maybe using Instruments ? Is there a way to figure out what psn_0_10148269 means?

Some parts of my app use (many) NSTask objects. Could that process be a not terminated NSTask object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a pretty weird message. The process is just your app itself. OS X passes in the `-psn` argument when it launches your app -- it's an implementation detail, that normally you never see.

It could definitely be something relating to an NSTask. Possibly you are running a task but never reaping its exit status; then your app becomes a [zombie process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process).  Double-check your NSTask usage, and make sure you aren't leaking any of them.

Also, it never hurts to ask the Apple reviewer for a clarification.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I'll have a look at all my NSTask instances.  Is there a way for me to ensure that this isn't happening anymore?? That would be very helpful.

Comment: Impossible to say whether it's fixed, until you find out the real cause of the problem!  I'd run your app and watch it, and its tasks, in Activity Monitor, or `ps` or `top` in the Terminal. I know `ps` can show zombie tasks ("Z" in the "STAT" column), don't know about the others.

Comment: Update: It was all my fault. I forgot that I wrote code some time ago that under special circumstances prevented the app from quitting if it still waits for a answer of a server. But if that answer never comes.... That was only for testing and I forgot to remove it. Nevertheless, thank you for your help!